# Disappearing mouse cursor in Word, Notepad, Outlook

Tags: display

I purchased a lenovo led monitor as a second monitor so I have dual screens now. Everything works great except all text programs make my cursor disappear on the new monitor. Everything works great on the old monitor but if I drag a text document to the new screen the cursor is invisible.

Any ideas on what to try?

Odd to me that it works on one and not the other so assuming it has something to do with the monitor but none of the settings seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try updating the graphics card drivers